# Capture right click on column/bar

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts upgraded their library to version 3. But in this version I can't capture the mouse's right click like before:

```
chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container-chart-1',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    (...),
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function(e) {
                      alert('LEFT CLICK YEAH!');
                    },
                    contextmenu: function (e) {
                        alert('RIGHT CLICK NOT SO YEAH!');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, (...)
```

I'm still on version 2 since I cannot make it to work.

Ideas and thoughts would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting, I was sure that setting context menu in that way doesn't work since 1-2years. Now, possible way is to add custom events using `Element.on()`, for example:

```
for(var j in chart.series){
    var series = chart.series[j];
    for(var i in series.data){
        (function(i){
            var point = series.data[i];
            if(point.graphic){
                point.graphic.on('contextmenu', function(e){
                    // show your context menu
                }); 
            }
        })(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, it brings up my contextmenu! :) But now I'm struggling with knowing which of the bars (index) and which of the series I clicked...

Comment: Can you show a working JSFiddle? Please explane more that where we should write above code?

Comment: In `load` callback it should be added.

Comment: Dear Pawel I'm very very sorry .Can you please show A JsFiddle demo? or a sample ? I'm confusing about right click on high chart.Thanks